# React context api, pass data from child to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

Currently I am using reactjs context api in my react app and I want to pass data from child component to parent component but I am not sure how I can achieve that. This is my full app layout:

```
-  Component 1 (App.js) [contextOneProvider]
  -  Component 2  
    -  Component 3  ==> Need a state from child component 7
      -  Component 4
        -  Component 5 [contextOneConsumer, getting state from component 1]
          -  Component 6 
            -  Component 7 ==> Need to send a state to parent component 3
              -  Component 8 [contextOneConsumer, getting state from component 1]
```

As you can see above, I already created one context(contextOne) which the provider of contextOne is used on component 1 and consumer of contextOne is used on component 5 and component 8. Now parent component 3 need a piece of data/state from child component 7 and here is the problem, how do I pass a piece of data/state from child component 7 back up to parent component 3?

If I do it without the react context api, I need to pass a function/method down from parent component 3 to child component 7 and call it in child component 7 and pass data/state back up, which I don't want to do it this way, because it's a deep prop drilling and component 4, component 5, component 6 don't need that function/method, it only exist in component 4, component 5 and component 6 is because I need it to pass down to child component 7 to use it.

Another way I can think of is to create another new context(contextTwo) and use the new context’s provider on component 3 and consumer on component 7, but create a whole new context just to pass that one piece of data/state back up to parent component 3, I also don't think this is a good idea.

**Code:**

Parent component 3

```
const componentThree = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span> // Receive someRandomId value from child component 7 and use in here </span>
      <ComponentFour/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Child component 7

```
const componentSeven = () => {

  const handleOnClick = () => {
    // Pass someRandomId value back up to parent component 3
    const someRandomId = 4;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <ComponentEight/>
      <button onClick={handleOnClick} ></button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So how do I pass a piece of data/state from child component 7 back up to parent component 3 without prop drilling or creating a whole new context just to pass that one piece of data/state back up to parent?

Sorry, this is my first time using react context api.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to avoid creating a new context:

add a new state in the provider component:

```
const [randonmId, setRandomId] = useState();
```

add both `randomId` and `setRandomId` to the value that is passed to the provider

```
value={{...previous things, randomId, setRandomId }}
```

use the context in component 3 but only to get `randomId`

also, use the context in component 7 and use the `setRandomId` inside the handler

```
  const handleOnClick = () => {
    const someRandomId = 4;
    setRandomId(someRandomId);
  };
```

in component 3:

```
{randomId && <span>{randomId}</span>}
```

because `randomId` would be undefined until comp 7's handler is called

Comment: Hi, sorry just to make sure, "add both ```randomId``` and ```setRandomId``` to the value that is passed to the provider" you mean the current existing context's provider(in component 1) right?

Comment: @JustANewCoder Yes